# field not displayed on WorkItem after adding through Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have successfully added field to the process using Rest API's.

when I call the following

Post https://my.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processdefinitions/a949f163-8d2c-4183-b26b-8f5b5385ef15/workItemTypes/my.ProductBacklogItem/fields?api-version=4.1-preview

​with following Json

{
 "defaultValue": null,
 "referenceName": "my.test",
 "name": "test",
 "type": "string",
 "readOnly": false,
 "required": false,
 "pickList": null,
 "url": null,
 "allowGroups": null
}

it returns me the following success msg

{
 "referenceName": "my.test",
 "name": "test",
 "type": "string",
 "pickList": null,
 "readOnly": false,
 "required": false,
 "defaultValue": null,
 "url": "https://my.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processDefinitions/a949f163-8d2c-4183-b26b-8f5b5385ef15/workItemTypes/my.ProductBacklogItem/fields/my.test",
 "allowGroups": null
}

however in the VSTS the field is not displayed on the workItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just added the new field to PBI work item, but don’t add control reference that field to PBI work item.

Refer to this request to add new control to PBI work item:

```
Put https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/work/processDefinitions/{process template id}/workItemTypes/my.ProductBacklogItem/layout/groups/my.Product Backlog Item.Product Backlog Item.Details/Controls/my.test?api-version=4.1-preview
```

Body: application/json

```
{"order":null,"label":"testcontrol","readOnly":false,"visible":true,"controlType":null,"metadata":null,"inherited":null,"overridden":null,"watermark":null,"contribution":null,"height":null,"isContribution":false}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for this part of the API yet? ANd does this also work on TFS 2018.1?

Comment: Thank you so much for the support but how would I know the name of the group.

Comment: @Flex You can to do it through UI and capture the requests, then analysis the requests.

Comment: @Naveed The work item types REST API includes Group information: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-item-types#get-a-work-item-type. On the other hand, feel free to open new thread if you have the issue.